# Can you create an associative array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am trying to set up an associative array in JavaScript and then store it in HTML5 Local Storage:

```
var student = [];
student["david"] = "He is doing very well";
localStorage['student'] = JSON.stringify(student);
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage['student']);
alert(data.david);
```

Comment: As an addition to @meagar, if you want an "associative array" just use an object. `var student = {}`.

Comment: You must be in a search of normal objects. `var student = {};
student["david"] = "He is doing very well";`

Comment: @meager Please see the following link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp which clearly points out that you are incorrect. They do exist, although they act a lot like objects. Please revise your down-vote.

Comment: @SamG Please don't tell other people how to vote. And my downvote is because you clearly did *no* debugging here, or you'd have found that your `JSON.stringify` strips away your property. Finally, **stop using w3schools**. That article is *laughably* wrong, and is giving you some terribly incorrect ideas about how arrays work in JavaScript.

Comment: @SamG — Quoting that link: "JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes."

Comment: That W3Schools article has many things about it which *are* laughable wrong, and even the above statement isn't *entirely* true … but the cause of your probably is that you are using an array (which *expects* property names to be numeric (more to the point JSON.stringify expects property names in arrays to be numeric)) and not an object (which doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as an "associative array" in JavaScript. You are using a regular array which requires the use of numeric indexes, and adding arbitrary properties to it, which are ignored when you serialize the array to JSON.

The JSON-stringified result will be: `"[]"`.

You need to use a real object:

```
var student = {}
```

Comment: @SamG — That link says "JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes."

Comment: @meager You are clearly right. I apologies for the lack of knowledge.

Comment: @SamG Lack of knowledge is excusable, but your need to learn to debug these problems yourself before asking others for help. Your questions has **nothing** to do with `localStorage`, and simply checking the return values from your method calls would have shown you that the property never makes it through `JSON.stringify`.